# Prevent iPhone being reset to factory settings and changing the Apple ID associated to bypass ScreenTime

Tags: apple-id, mobile-device-management, parental-controls

It's my personal parent control issue.

I have an iPhone and MacBook which has screen time. My kid can bypass it

- By spamming unlock it seems that there is a way to prolong extra time endlessly!
- By doing factory reset kid simply can resign to new appleid to device without problem!

The answer is, the Mobile Device Management for iPhone and proprietary company lock for apple laptops provided for companies.

How can I have this for family causes?

Comment: FindMy should prevent anyone resetting & taking over the phone on a new Apple ID.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to list out the specific device and iOS version you're using. Generally though -

In ScreenTime you can disable account changes. You can only change accounts in iOS after a reset if you removed the account before resetting.

Otherwise, there are MDM controls you could implement through something like JAMF (or another MDM), eg. Disable “Erase All Content and Settings”

Anyone can buy and install an MDM, you don't need to be an enterprise. There are plenty of free options out there too.

Jamf make a [guide](https://www.jamf.com/resources/product-documentation/jamf-parent-guide-for-parents/) specifically for families. They used to offer a free 3-device family plan, I don't see it any more.